# oracle sql need help on data according to pattern

Tags: sql, oracle

I have sample data in oracle database shown below :

```
set_no  set_eff_dt    set_term_dt
1000    1/1/2015    12/31/2016
1000    1/1/2017    10/31/2017
1000    11/1/2017   12/31/2018
1000    2/1/2019    10/31/2019
1000    11/1/2019   10/31/2020
```

I want the Out Like below

```
1000    1/1/2015    12/31/2018
1000    2/1/2019    10/31/2020
```

Let me Explain the Pattern and how the out put will Come

In the second row `set_off_dt` is result of  `set_term_dt +1`

In the third row `set_off_dt` is result of  `set_term_dt +1` of second row

In the 4th row `set_eff_dt` is not a result of `set_term_dt+1` from third row so here is group break may b

In the 5th row `set_eff_dt` is again a result of `set_term_dt+1` from 4th row 
so it will be collapsed with 4th row as shown in output

In this same pattern we have thousand of records and we want to collapsed as per logic described

```
what i have tried

SELECT SET_NO,SET_EFF_DT,
 case when LEAD (SET_EFF_DT,1) OVER (ORDER BY SET_EFF_DT)-1 = set_trm_dt then 1 else 0 end flg
 FROM xx_fl_test
```

I was just able to identify the flag if `SET_EFF_DT` = `set_trm_dt` in new row... But still i dont got understand how tackle the collapsed on behalf of this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider cumulatively summing your generated column to produce a grouping variable which requires two CTEs: one for your *flg* calculation, and second for cumulative sum of *flg* with a window function. Finally, aggregate by *cum_flg* (but conditionally add 1 for the very first grouping value which starts as 1).

```
WITH sub AS
  (SELECT SET_NO, SET_EFF_DT, SET_TRM_DT,
          CASE WHEN LEAD (SET_EFF_DT,1) OVER (ORDER BY SET_EFF_DT)-1 = SET_TRM_DT
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
          END AS flg
   FROM xx_fl_test),

   calc AS
   (SELECT SET_NO, SET_EFF_DT, SET_TRM_DT,
           SUM (flg) OVER (PARTITION BY SET_NO ORDER BY SET_EFF_DT)  AS cum_flg
    FROM sub)

SELECT SET_NO, 
       MIN(SET_EFF_DT) AS MIN_SET_EFF_DT,
       MAX(SET_TRM_DT) AS MAX_SET_TRM_DT
FROM calc
GROUP BY SET_NO,
         CASE cum_flg
              WHEN 1
              THEN cum_flg + 1
         END
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/OFKZ19480)

Comment: Still not as per Desired output as i shown in my question

Comment: ` with lines as (
  select row_number() over (partition by SET_NO, SET_TY_CD order by SET_EFF_DT) - 
           row_number() over (partition by  SET_NO, SET_TY_CD order by SET_EFF_DT) grp, 
         a.*
  from   xx_fl_test a
)
  select SET_NO, SET_TY_CD, 
         min(SET_EFF_DT) st, 
         max(SET_TRM_DT) en 
  from   lines l
  group  by SET_NO, SET_TY_CD, grp
  order  by min(SET_EFF_DT) ;`

Comment: as per this i am not able to break on first dataset

Comment: The rextester demo does show your desired output with different date/time formats. But glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  I would solve by calculating a grouping variable, in the following steps:

1. Determine where a group begins.  For this, I do a lag on the previous `set_trm_dt` and `case` logic to see if there is no "connection".
2. Do a cumulative sum of the the flag, to assign a `grp` to each row.
3. Aggregate by `grp`.

The code looks like this:

```
select set_no, min(set_eff_dt), max(set_trm_dt)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when set_eff_dt > prev_set_trm_dt + 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by set_no order by set_eff_dt) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(set_trm_dt) over (partition by set_no order by set_eff_dt) as prev_set_trm_dt
            from xx_fl_test t
           ) t
     ) t
group by set_no, grp;
```